# MySQL INSERT problem

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Does anyone know what is problem with this query:

```
INSERT INTO match 
  (IDTeamHome, IDTeamGuest, Date) 
VALUES 
  ('15','16','20.03.2011 15:00')
```

IDTeamHome and IDTeamGuest are integer, and Date is varchar.

Comment: Why would you store date & time in a VARCHAR column!?  There's no obvious error with what you posted, you'll have to provide the error you experience to get an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: there are several issues.

1. "match" and "date" [are keywords in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). You need double-quotes or backticks around them so that MySQL knows that they are table or column names, e.g.
   `INSERT INTO "match" (id1, id2, "date") VALUES ...`
2. Remove the single-quotes around the integer values you're inserting.
   Single-quotes are for strings. (not strictly necessary as pointed out by OMG Ponies in the comments)
3. If you can avoid it, do not store timestamps as VARCHAR. This will make querying more difficult and confuse anyone else who's working with your table(s).

Comment: MySQL (and most other databases for that matter) performs implicit conversion in situations like these, based on the column data type.  But it is good habit not to rely on it, for sake of attempting to provide data that can not be implicitly converted.

Comment: Why single quotes don't work in his case? Is related to some sql mode?

Comment: Actually, I missed that the `date` column is VARCHAR

Comment: so, what is the answer? If the date column is VARCHAR? Thanks

Comment: @dzosef: if the column is varchar your code should be working as written. Please post the exact error you're getting.

Comment: INSERT INTO match (IDTeamHome,IDTeamGuest,Datum) VALUES (17,18,'20.03.2011 15:00').
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match (IDTeamHome,IDTeamGuest,Datum) VALUES (17,18,'20.03.2011 15:00')' at line 120.03.2011 20:45

Comment: "match" is a keyword in MySQL. Place backticks or double-quotes around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Date` or rename this field, because Date is a word used by MySQL I think.

And remove the single quotes for the integers.

Comment: Now it is this code INSERT INTO match (IDTeamHome,IDTeamGuest,`Datum`) VALUES (11,12,'20.03.2011 15:00')

Comment: @dzosef: don't store dates in a `varchar` column.

Comment: I want to store in varchar column, because it's not gonna be date every time. So I don't catch what's the problem with my code if it is regular varchar

INSERT INTO match (IDTeamHome,IDTeamGuest,SomeField) VALUES (7,8,'blah blah').

Answer (score 0):

match is a reserved word.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Rename your table or put it within backticks (alt + 96)

I've seen it just now. :)

Answer (score 0):

ID Of Team is Int so you can't use single quotations because that's quotations. For String value Like Alphabets, use this format:

```
insert into match(int,varchar(20),data)
Values(12,'teamname','2015-11-4');
```